# This Twitter API script takes over a minute to load

Tags: twitter, simplexml

I am using a very simple Twitter PHP script to get the most recent 2 tweets but sometimes it takes over a minute to load. Is this code not optimized?

```
    <?php
        function getTwitterStatus($userid){
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/$userid.xml?count=2&include_rts=1callback=?";

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("could not connect");

               foreach($xml->status as $status){
               $text = $status->text;
               }
               echo $text;
         }
     getTwitterStatus("BillGates",1);?>
```

Comment: why you don't use php's curl() to fetch data from twitter api it is very fast

Comment: use this library [php library for twitter api](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) it give you access to do everything that twitter allowed to do. Here all things mention on this page can be done with above library [twitter link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)